# Double Pulse Test Schematic Review

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, power-electronics, mosfet-driver, gate-driving

[image]

Hello all! I am new to Altium PCB Design. Can anyone give a review on the schematic before I move on to the layout? Should I include more net classes? If yes, where and why?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a two-output gate driver for a single output?

Comment: R3, no HV supply capacitor, and a lack of indicated Kelvin source connections for Q2 may cause you to have a bad time.

Comment: @Hearth to match the actual intended converter (gate loop parasitics) which uses dual output gate driver for driving mosfets

Comment: @W5VO didn't get your lack of Kelvin source connection point, what does it mean? What will happen?

Comment: You want to isolate the gate drive loop from the drain-source current loop to minimize the impact of switched current on your gate voltage. Imagine you have a few (5) nH of inductance If you have a sudden change in drain-source current. If the drain-source current was changing at say 1 A/ns, then it will develop 5V across the source lead, turning off your transistor. Your transistor will oscillate between on and off, with possibly explosive results.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the schematic looks pretty good.

I always try to add detail to the circuit because in six months (or sometimes a day) I'll forget what it does. Here are some suggestions:

- Add names to nets (under place/net_label). It makes it easier to find traces.
- Add colors to nets to make it easier see what is connected to what (under view/set net colors). I typically do this to traces like GND which go to a bunch of things. Or when you have multiple grounds like you do.
- Remove pin numbers for non-polarized parts such a resistors.
- It appears that your capacitors have a reference designator that are only numbers? I'd add a C before the number.
- For your input power connectors, add a text box (under place / text_frame) indicating the input voltage (nominal and maximum) and current. For output connectors I'll put the voltage range. Labeling connectors as an input or output isn't a bad thing.
- If I'm handing the schematic off to someone else I sometimes put a note in the bottom left indicating what the circuit does.
- Use net classes to group traces that are special in the layout. For example, is the trace a high voltage trace which requires additional spacing? Are the traces impedance controlled? Do the traces pass high current? If yes, then I assign a net class. I usually use a net class name like "50_Ohm", "1_A", "250_VDC", small enough to fit on the schematic, but easy to understand.

Comment: Thank-you for your inputs @C. Dunn ! Any specific layout guidelines from your side? Operating DC voltage : 100V, operating current : around 30A.

Comment: 100 V will set your spacing between traces and components. Follow the spacing guidelines of the IPC-2221 [Generic Standard on Printed Board Design](https://shop.ipc.org/ipc-2221/ipc-2221-standard-only/Revision-b/english). 30 A will set your trace width, which is listed in the IPC-2152 [Standard for Determining Current Carrying Capacity in Printed Board Design](https://shop.ipc.org/ipc-2152/ipc-2152-standard-only/Revision-0/english). The free software [Saturn PCB toolkit](https://saturnpcb.com/saturn-pcb-toolkit/) has calculators for both. If the traces are too wide, you might need wires.